# Declaring Design-Time ViewModel for Avalonia Window

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, avaloniaui

I'm looking for the right approach to declare design-time ViewModel for an Avalonia window.

Some samples suggest

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:LoginViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

This throws

```
XamlParseException at 5:5: Unable to resolve type DesignInstance from namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008
```

Default Avalonia MVVM template suggests

```
<Design.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Design.DataContext>
```

If the ViewModel takes parameters, it throws

```
XamlLoadException at 16:10: Unable to find public constructor for type Demo.CloseNonModalDialog:Demo.CloseNonModalDialog.CurrentTimeDialogViewModel()
```

I guess adding a default parameter-less constructor is an option.

With MvvmLight/WPF, I used to reference the ViewLocator as a static resource

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainWindow}"
```

That's an option, although I haven't yet found the right way to declare and reference the resource.

What is the recommended approach here? If I want to show design-time data, I'd say only the 3rd option would work. Which is not the option shown in samples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Unable to find public constructor for type Demo.CloseNonModalDialog:Demo.CloseNonModalDialog.CurrentTimeDialogViewModel()

You can specify arguments via `x:Arguments` XAML directive, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/xarguments-directive

> That's an option, although I haven't yet found the right way to declare and reference the resource.

I'd suggest to declare `DesignData` class and use `x:Static`, it will give you way more flexibility. e. g.

```cs
class DesignData
{
    public MyViewModel MyViewModel => new MyViewModel(...);
}
```

`d:DataContext="{x:Static local:DesignData.MyViewModel}"`

View model creation would also not happen during the normal app execution unlike the StaticResource approach.

Comment: That works and is clean enough, thanks